# Validate html form when button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I need to validate HTML form when click and display error message if the field is empty or else I try to do that using JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#idnext').click(function () {

             $("#fromtopupvalues").validate({
                messages: {

                    usernfidtxt:{required: "Please enter your nf id",},
                    first_name: {required:"Please enter a first name",},
                    last_name: {required:"Please enter a last name",},
                    email: {required:"Please enter a valid email address",},
                    phone: {required:"Please enter a valid phone number",},
                    address: {required:"Please enter a valid address",},
                    city: {required:"Please enter your City",},
                    country: {required:"Please enter your Country",},
                    amount: {required:"Please enter your amount",},
                },
                rules: {
                    usernfidtxt: "required",
                    first_name: "required",
                    last_name: "required",

                    email: {// compound rule
                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                    },

                    phone:{
                        required: true,
                        pattern: "^[0-9-+s()]*$",
                    },
                    address: "required",
                    city: "required",
                    country: "required",
                    amount: "required",
                },

              });

          })


        });
</script>
```

In HTML form I have following code

```
    <div class="container">
                    <div class="stepwizard col-md-offset-3">
                        <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
                          <div class="stepwizard-step">
                            <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
                            <p>Payment form</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="stepwizard-step">
                            <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
                            <p>Summary</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                      <form role="form" id="fromtopupvalues" action="" method="post">
                        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
                          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                              <h4> Payment form</h4>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="useridtxt">TOPUP User NFC ID <span style="color: red" >*</span> :</label>
                                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="usernfidtxt" placeholder="TOPUP User NFC ID" name="usernfcidtxt" min="0" required >
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="first_name">First Name <span style="color: red" >*</span> :</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" required>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="last_name">Last Name <span style="color: red" >*</span> :</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" required>

                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="email">Email <span style="color: red" >*</span> :</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="phone">Phone number <span style="color: red" >*</span> :</label>
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone number" pattern="^[0-9-+s()]*$" name="phone" required>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="address">Address <span style="color: red" >*</span> :</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Address" name="address" required></textarea>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="city">City <span style="color: red" >*</span> :</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" name="city" required>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="country">Country <span style="color: red" >*</span> :</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" id="country" placeholder="Country" name="country" value="Sri Lanka" required>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="idamounttxt">Amount (Rs.)<span style="color: red" >*</span> :</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" placeholder="Amount" name="amount" min="0">
                              </div>
                              <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" id="idnext" type="button" onclick="showInput();" >Next</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
                          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                              <h4> Summary</h4>
                              <div class="row">
                                    <div class="well col-lg-12 ">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                                <address>
                                                    <strong><span id='Rc_addressheader'>Elf Cafe</span></strong>
                                                    <br><span id='Rc_addressline1'>2135 Sunset Blvd,Los Angeles, CA 90026</span><br>
                                                    <span id='Rc_addresscuntry'>Sri Lanka</span><br>
                                                    <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr><span id='Rc_addressPhone'>(213) 484-6829</span><br>
                                                    <abbr title="Email">E:</abbr><span id='Rc_addressemail'>test@gmail.com</span>
                                                </address>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-right">
                                                <p>
                                                    <em>Date:<span id='Rc_date'>1st November, 2013</span></em>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="text-center">
                                                <h1>Summary</h1>
                                            </div>
                                            </span>
                                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th><h4>Payment </h4></th>
                                                        <th class="text-center"><h4>Price (Rs.)</h4></th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="col-md-9"><em><strong>TOPUP value</strong></em></h4></td>
                                                        <td class="col-md-1 text-center"><span id='Rc_price'><strong>26</strong></span></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="col-md-9"><em><strong>SubPayment</strong></em></h4></td>
                                                        <td class="col-md-1 text-center"><span id='Rc_SubPayment'>50</span></td>
                                                    </tr>
<!--                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="text-right">
                                                        <p>
                                                            <strong>Subtotal: </strong>
                                                        </p>
                                                        <p>
                                                            <strong>Tax: </strong>
                                                        </p></td>
                                                        <td class="text-center">
                                                        <p>
                                                            <strong><span id='Rc_subtotal'>26</span></strong>
                                                        </p>
                                                        <p>
                                                            <strong>50</strong>
                                                        </p></td>
                                                    </tr>-->
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="text-right"><h4><strong>Total: </strong></h4></td>
                                                        <td class="text-center text-danger"><h4><strong>Rs.<span id='Rc_Total'>31.53</span>/=</strong></h4></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
                                                Pay Now   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                            </button></td>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                </div>
```

What I need is when user click the next form I need to validate the Payment form using JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: what does your code do now?

Comment: you want to validate on button click right?

Comment: your form has id `fromtopupvalues` and there is no `usernfidtxt` in your form. It's `usernfcidtxt` and no need to wrap your validate function inside `click` event.

Comment: basically i need to validate the HTML textbox when click the Next(id="idnext") button

Comment: put your `.validate()` code outside of button's `click` handler. And inside `click` handler just execute the form validation by `$("#fromtopupvalues").valid();`.

Comment: i did change usernfcidtxt to usernfidtxt I tried that also and but i can't see the expected result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi just check the below fiddle. Updated your code and now it seems working. Just call $("#registerform").valid(); inside your button click. Also move your validation declarations to outside of the click function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#registerform").validate({
    messages: {

      usernfidtxt: {
        required: "Please enter your nf id"
      },
      first_name: {
        required: "Please enter a first name"
      },
      last_name: {
        required: "Please enter a last name"
      },
      email: {
        required: "Please enter a valid email address"
      },
      phone: {
        required: "Please enter a valid phone number"
      },
      address: {
        required: "Please enter a valid address"
      },
      city: {
        required: "Please enter your City"
      },
      country: {
        required: "Please enter your Country"
      },
      amount: {
        required: "Please enter your amount"
      }
    },
    rules: {
      usernfidtxt: "required",
      first_name: "required",
      last_name: "required",

      email: { // compound rule
        required: true,
        email: true,
      },

      phone: {
        required: true,
        pattern: "^[0-9-+s()]*$",
      },
      address: "required",
      city: "required",
      country: "required",
      amount: "required",
    },

  });



  $('#idnext').click(function() {
    $("#registerform").valid();

  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sreerajsaseendran/ck4oa39h/1/

Comment: can i know that if any field is empty can i hide or disable the Next button ?

Comment: If you hide or disable the next button, how this validation will work?? You want to remove validations?

Comment: You can do that by using if($("#registerform").valid()) condition. But you need to check this in each elements change. I did not tried this. Just a guess.

Comment: i did try that too